# Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66384 > 65536)

Tags: android

Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66384 > 65536)

Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66384 > 65536)

Answer (score 1):

```
Add multidex library support to your android code like

    android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

also follow the link for more details 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#java
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the answer from Anand is correct (well at least worked for me)
You may need to check what is the latest version of multidex available and use that one - currently it is 2.0.1 - see here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/multidex

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.pacakge.name"
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Ref: https://devmainapps.blogspot.com/2020/05/android-studio-cannot-fit-requested.html

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file change the

```
    minSdkVersion 21
```

Change MinSdKVersion To 21